# how to solve Unsupported Media Type 415 using spring boot and angular4?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, angular-services

I am using angular 4 and spring Boot,while i execute the project in command line getting error(Unsupported Media Type 415)..

**ang.service.ts:**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http,RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
@Injectable()
export class shopService {
  handleError: any;
  headers: any;
  private shopUrl = '/api/createRecord';
  private header = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}); 

  constructor(private http: Http) {}

  createShop(shopcreate: any): Promise<any> {       
   this.headers});      
    return this.http
     .post(this.shopUrl,JSON.stringify(shopcreate), {headers: this.headers})
     .toPromise()
     .then(res => res.json() as any)
    .catch(this.handleError);
  }
}
```

**springboot Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/createRecord",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String shop(@RequestBody Shop shops) {
        String shopname = request.getParameter("shopname");
        System.out.println("Welcome to new Create Record Shop Name: " + shopname);
        return "";      
    }
```

Error:

```
 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 415 Unsupported Media Type for URL: http://localhost:4200/api/createRecord
at resolvePromise (zone.js:710) [angular]
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:681) [angular]
    at polyfills.bundle.js:3364:17 [angular]
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.es5.js:3881) [angular]
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:591) [<root>]
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:464) [<root>]
```

[Error image  in browser consel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZK8O.png)

Comment: Try to do `console.log(JSON.stringify(shopcreate))` and post output here.

Comment: 1. You don't need to stringify, and to set the content type. Http does that for you. 2. Http is deprecated, use HttpClient (it also does that for you. 3. Do you jae Jackson in the classpath at server-side? It's necessary to handle JSON.

Comment: See the console  error in Browser https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZK8O.png...@ hrdkisback

Comment: Try to pass `shopcreate` object only like this `this.http
     .post(this.shopUrl, shopcreate, {headers: this.headers})`, also you should import `Headers` like this `import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';`